# Quickbook to Salesforce Integration

Tags: apex, rest-api, quickbooks-api

I am using `quickbook API` for integrating with `salesforce`.I have created an app on developer account on intuit.
From there we got the `consumer key` and `consumer secret`. using both i am creating a signature using `Hmac-Sha1` method.I got the error `oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_signature`. Plz suggest

Answer (score 1):

OAuth usually requires that the values be URL parameters, not HTTP headers. Try changing your code as follows:

```
String body = String.format(
    'oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_signature_method={1}&oauth_signature={2}&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_nonce={4}&oauth_version={5}',
    new String[] {
        consumerkey,    // the key
        'HMAC-SHA1',    // the method
        signaure12,     // the signature
        s1,             // the timestamp
        nonce,          // the nonce
        '1.0'}          // the version
);
req.setBody(body);
```

Comment: `req.getParameters().putAll` is not supporting here

Comment: @Aisha You're right, I forgot myself. Try the new version.

Comment: thank you! i'm able to authenticate all API from Quickbook now.

Comment: I am using above code but unable to get the result getting error as 401 Unauthorized "oauth_problem=signature_invalid"